# What is the notify-send alternative command in Pop! OS

Tags: linux, pop-os, notifications, notify-send

I use `notify-send` in **Manjaro Linux** to send notifications, as follows:

```
notify-send [OPTIONS] [Message Summary] [Message Body]
```

However, I moved to Pop! OS and I found that `command not found: notify-send`

I heard that notify-send is dead, so I am trying to get an alternative command to send notifications in Pop! OS

Is it also possible to install notify-send in Pop! OS?

Comment: PoP! OS is based on Ubuntu. So whatever works on Ubuntu will work on Pop! OS. All you need to do is find out what particular package does that job in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, `notify-send` works fine in **Pop! OS** but just is not installed by default. There is no need for an alternative command.  We just need to install `libnotify-bin`.

I was able to install and use notify-send successfully using the following command:

```
sudo apt install libnotify-bin
notify-send "Yes! It works!"
```

Answer (score 3):

As previously mentioned, you could install `libnotify-bin` and use `notify-send`. However, if you're looking for an out of the box solution to send notifications, you can use d-bus:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications --object-path /org/freedesktop/Notifications --method org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify "YourAppName" "0" "Icon Path" "Notification Title" "Notification Message" "[]" "{}" 1500
```

- The "0" you see there is a "Replaces ID", which makes this notification replace another one by its ID.
- "[]" is the list of actions.
- "{}" is a map of hints.
- 1500 is the expiration timeout in milliseconds.

Example:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications --object-path /org/freedesktop/Notifications --method org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify "YourAppName" "0" "/usr/share/icons/Pop/32x32/devices/battery.svg" "Battery low!" "Your <u>Zune</u>'s battery is less than <b>20%</b>" "[]" "{}" 1500
```

You generally only care about the **icon**, notification **title**, notification **body**, and the **expiration time**, but if you want to lear more, check out the docs: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html

Comment: the example didnt work for me